# oracle object types and their members in ado.net entity data model

Tags: oracle, entity-framework, ado.net, ef-database-first, object-type

How to use oracle object types and their members in ado.net entity data model?
When I add ado.net entity data model from database,  I can use tables, views, stored procedures and functionss, but I can't get object types and their members.
Also, I dont know how to use packages.
I googled for that, but it was in vein.

Answer (score 0):

If ado.net entity data model does not understand these Oracle datatypes, then you need to translate them on the Oracle side to something that the ado.net entity data model understands.